# create object of abstract class c++

Tags: c++

in my project I have `IAcquirer.h` file and the content of the file is like below

```
class IAcquirer {

        public:
            IAcquirer() {}
            virtual ~IAcquirer() {}
            virtual int initAcquirer(std::string ) = 0;
            virtual int processTransactionToHost(const transaction::Transaction &tr, transaction::TransactionDataContainer &txnDataContainer) =0;
            virtual int connect(bool) =0;
            virtual int disconnect(void) =0;
        };
```

Now in another file called `system.cpp` , object of the class `IAcquirer`  is created

```
boomer::host::IAcquirer *pAcquirer;
pAcquirer->processTransactionToHost(****,***);
```

But from my understanding we cant create object of abstract class , Now the object is being created in other file

Comment: That's not object, it's a pointer

Comment: So we can declare a pointer and call the function of the class ?

Comment: You should read more about C++, including reference [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) (and spend weeks reading some [good book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) about C++). You should compile with all warnings and debug info, `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), then improve your code to get no warnings. And your should **use the debugger** `gdb`.

Comment: If you copied the two lines exactly, it is an error.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct, you cannot create an object of an abstract class.

However, you can create objects derived from an abstract class. These objects are compatible with their base abstract class, and could be manipulated through a pointer or a reference typed as the abstract base.

For example, this is valid:

```
class RealAcquirer : public IAcquirer {
    virtual int initAcquirer(std::string ) {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    ... // Other pure virtual member functions implememted here
};

IAcquirer *make() {
    return new RealAcquirer();
}
```

Once you get a pointer to `IAcquirer`, you can call any of `IAcquirer`'s member functions through it, including pure virtual member functions overridden in the derived class.

Comment: Note: You need the other virtual methods as well to be defined

Comment: @EdHeal Right, all other pure virtual member functions need to be implemented as well. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: IAcquirer *make() , we can call this function from any where ?

Comment: @TUHINSUBHRAPANDA Correct, you can call this function from anywhere where it is in scope, including places where `RealAcquirer` is *not* in scope.

Comment: If the same function ("processTransactionToHost()") is define in the derived class then , will it be called when we are calling like pAcquirer->processTransactionToHost(****,***);

Comment: @TUHINSUBHRAPANDA The override from derived class will be called.

Comment: @TUHINSUBHRAPANDA You are welcome. If this answers your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the gray check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: While this is certainly a viable answer to the question I strongly urge you to change the `make()` function to return `std::unique_ptr<IAcquirer>` (or some other memory management wrapper). Returning owning raw pointers from a creation function is one of the patterns that has been causing memory leaks and endless headaches for decades. Here it’s especially detrimental. Don’t teach beginners harmful practices!